# Determinada função não funciona no Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Tenho uma condicional assim:

```
     // 1.º - Verificar se existe a matrícula no sistema
                 function existeColaborador()
                     {
                         if(DSdetalhesColaborador.values[0] == undefined)
                             {
                        //alert('Matricula inválida');
                        limpaCampos();
                        return false;
                    }
                         else
                             {
                        if ((DSibrr.values.length < 1) && (DSdetalhesColaborador.values[0]['Situacao'] == 'A'))
                            {
                            return true;
                            }
                    }
                     } // fim da função
```

E depois abaixo no codigo tenho minha função:

```
     if(existeColaborador() == false)
                {
                alert('Não existe Colaborador com essa matrícula')
                }
                else
                {
                  // DSdetalhesColaborador.values[0]['Situacao'] = 'D';

               if (tipoSolicitacao == 'complementar')
                    {
                     if (DSdetalhesColaborador.values[0]['Situacao'] == 'A')
           {
                         alert("Não é possível realizar uma Rescisão Complementar para um Colaborador ATIVO!");
                         limpaCampos();
                         }
                   else if  (DSdetalhesColaborador.values[0]['Situacao'] == 'D' && DSibrr.values.length > 0)
                     {
                      if  (DSdetalhesColaborador.values[0]['Situacao'] == 'D' && DSibrr.values[0]['tipoSolicitacao'] == 'complementar')
                       {

                                                 Ext.Msg.show({
                                msg: "Colaborador já está em processo de demissão no ECM. Iniciar novo Processo Complementar para o colaborador?",
                                buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                                icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                                fn: function(btn) {
                                        console.log(arguments);
                                        if (btn == 'yes') {
                                        preencheCampos()
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        limpaCampos()
                                        }
                                }
                        });
                         //alert('O Colaborador já teve um processo demissão iniciado ou finalizado no ECM!');
              //preencheCampos();
                       }
                      else if  (DSdetalhesColaborador.values[0]['Situacao'] == 'D' && DSibrr.values[0]['tipoSolicitacao'] == 'desligamento')
                       {
                           preencheCampos();
                         }
                     }
                     else
                 {
                         alert('O Colaborador ainda não tem um processo demissão iniciado ou finalizado no ECM!');
                         preencheCampos();
                     }


                    }
      } // fim da condicional
```

Ocorre que essa que no Chrome tudo funciona bem, 
mas no firefox ocorre erro dizendo:

> existeColaborador is not defined.

**Existe algum problema em chamar uma função dentro de uma condicional?**

[Segue arquivo rules](http://jsfiddle.net/Durtto/4u82whaf/)

a imagem abaixa mostra meu codigo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa imagem consta o erro no firefox:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque há uma mudança de identação na linha 478?

Comment: Na linha 478 consta um comentário instrutivo. Acima dela eu consumo web services e armazeno os valores em objetos. Posteriormente eu preciso fazer uma série de comparações desses valores, pois dependo de várias informações desses webservices. Exemplo: digito a matrícula do colaborador, se esse colaborador == demitido, eu não permito que faça sua demissão.

Comment: Tu queres resolver o problema ou saber o porquê de estar dando errado apenas no `firefox`?

Comment: Ok, Sergio, depois eu corrigo a tabulação, mas agora preciso entender o porquê do firefox não reconhecer a função. me ajude.

Comment: Eu quero entender @JéfersonBueno, entendido eu busco o conserto.

Comment: Você tem como postar o código completo das funções?

Comment: @EduardoSeixas mas nõ vejo motivo de mudar o indent depois de um coment... Dá para reproduzir o problema no jsFiddle por exemplo?

Comment: @EduardoSeixas, poste o código das funções. Não temos como adivinhar o que está causando o erro...

Comment: Tente passar a função para cima do código que a chama. E também tente limpar o cache do navegador e inspecionar se o seu código foi atualizado.

Comment: ok @JoaoPaulo vou tentar fazer isso, mas eu quero que funcione independente de onde a função está... Poderia até estar em outro arquivo, ela devia rodar, pois, lembrando, ela roda no 'chrome' mas não funciona no 'firefox'.

Comment: Passando a função para cima resolveu. Mas porque o firefox não entende da mesma forma que Chrome?

Comment: @EduardoSeixas Precisamos se possível de todo o código da rules.js, se não fica muito difícil tentar adivinhar olhando apenas pela imagem. Como sabemos o browser lê todo o arquivo antes de executar então o problema pode estar em outra parte que você nem imagina, por isso precisamos ver todo código para te dar uma resposta.

Comment: é muita coisa, mas tudo bem....

Comment: [segue rules] (http://jsfiddle.net/Durtto/4u82whaf)

Comment: @EduardoSeixas verifique sua versão do browser e mais importante se por acaso não existe nenhum outro javascript que por acaso tenha outra função ou variável com o mesmo nome dessa função. Pois eu executei aqui no firefox apenas o trecho com erro, e funciona normalmente (ele não da erro de function undefined) mesmo comigo passando a sua função de validação para depois do if, até porque em javascript isso é irrelevante desde que a function esteja na mesma closure do if.

Comment: Faça um teste simples. Mude o nome da função para algo que você tenha certeza que não quase impossível de ter sido utilizada no sistema, por exemplo testaasdasd() e veja se o erro continua.

Comment: Eu mudei sim, mas não vai adiantar mesmo. Veja essa resposta. O firefox realmente não suporta declaração de funcção em bloco.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111087/why-is-a-function-declaration-within-a-condition-block-hoisted-to-function-scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há diversas razões que podem fazer o seu código não funcionar, eis algumas dicas:

- Tente passar a função para cima do código que a chama.
- Limpe o cache do navegador e inspecione se o seu código foi atualizado.
- Finalize todos os seus scripts com ";" no final. (Vejo que há um alert() sem ;)

Obs: Versões antigas de navegador as vezes não interpretam da mesma forma que os mais atuais.

Answer (score 0):

Este erro ocorre quando a função não foi declarada antes de carregar a página,
tente incluir arquivo rules.js na sua View:

```
<script src="../10000/rules.js"></script>
```

ou declare a função antes de carregar a página.

Comment: Pelo que percebi a função é declarada no mesmo ficheiro, e na imagem `}` está lá.

Comment: realmente fica complicado de ficar adivinhando como ta a estrutura ali, mas se estiver no mesmo ficheiro, é só criar uma tag script antes da inicialização da página, do tipo text/javascript e declarar essa função existeColaborador lá, tem que funcionar.

Comment: Tens certeza que o script **funcionaria** no *Chrome* se não estivesse referenciado no `html`?

Comment: Está referenciado sim, já conferi.. o arquivo rules contêm a regra.